# windows larger than the screen

Tags: c++, winapi

After creating a (large enough) window programatically, the resize code is bugged unless I handle the `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message and set `ptMaxTrackSize.x` and `ptMaxTrackSize.y` large enough.

But then the window is a bit outside the screen (vertically). Horizontally I can still see the borders (thick border). I click on that border (`WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message, which the program does not handle) and the window becomes aligned to the top screen border (visible title bar).

How can I do this programatically (fixing the vertical positioning)?
So instead of having to click the border, what can I do from my software to tell Windows to re-align the window?

Comment: Set the x and y arguments to CreateWindow/Ex() to 0.

Comment: the problem is from repositioning after creation

Comment: Erm, don't reposition it?  MoveWindow() moves a window.

Comment: well, i need to resize it based on it's (dynamically created) child windows; and also to align it left/center/right/top/bottom - values that, baring heavy refactoring, I do not know at window creation. But it's solved, please see my comment on iedoc's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what your looking for?

[MoveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: no - i don't want to resize my window, just to move it so that the top window border is right at the top of the screen

Comment: Have you tried [MoveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534(VS.85).aspx)?

Comment: Honestly it would be a hassle to recalculate the second parameter of MoveWindow(hwnd,**x**,y,...)

Comment: scratch that, solved it by MoveWindow(hwnd,x,max(0,y),...   please edit your answer to the MoveWindow suggestion and I'll accept it